# Not able to run selenium with firefox, Capybara and Docker in headless mode

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to run tests with Selenium and Firefox with Capybara. When I run a test, it does a POST request to "http://127.0.0.1:4444:/sessions", it starts a server with `geckodriver` and I have a timeout error. I tried to do it manually by doing this command :

```
curl -d '{"desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox", "version": "", "platform": "ANY", "javascriptEnabled": 1, "cssSelectorsEnabled": 1, "takesScreenshot": 1, "nativeEvents": 0, "rotatable": 0, "unexpectedAlertBehaviour": "ignore", "moz:firefoxOptions": {"args": ["-headless"]}}, "capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{"browserName": "firefox", "moz:firefoxOptions": {}}]}}' http://127.0.0.1:4444/session
```

It fails and I have this message : `Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays`. When I lauch `xvfb-run geckodriver`, it works but I have to find a way to launch geckodriver in headless mode with RSpec.

I'm on a docker env, so I don't have a xserver installed.

What can I do?

### Edit

I have :

```
Firefox 52.4
Geckodriver 0.19.0
Capybara 2.13
Selenium-webdriver 3.6
```

Here is my configuration of selenium :

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  require 'selenium/webdriver'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

Everything is running on docker.

Comment: How are you configuring your Capybara driver, what versions of Capybara/Selenium/Firefox/geckodriver are you using? Is everything running on the docker environment (capybara, geckodriver, browser, etc), or just the browser?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I added some information

Comment: Geckodriver 0.19 only supports FF 55+ - upgrade Firefox.  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I have the same with firefox 56

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now that you have Firefox 56 (which is supported by geckodriver 0.19 and also supports headless mode, which Firefox 52 did not) you need to configure your driver to enable headless mode.  Something along the lines of

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new()
  browser_options.args << '--headless'

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :firefox,
    options: browser_options
  )
end
```

should do.